# Can TERGM be used to fit bunch of networks files from 1.net to n.net?

Tags: r, cran, statnet

Can TERGM be used to fit bunch of networks files from 1.net to n.net? With each file, the number of nodes and vertices increases. I have

For example, when we fit a particular network (suppose 6.net), we run the following after preprocessing the network (i.e finding the metrics value and adding the metrics to the nodes)

```
network_fit<-ergm(my_network~edges+nodecov("degree")+nodecov("betweenness")+nodecov("closeness")+nodecov("pagerank")+nodecov("eigen_c")+nodecov("clustcoeff"))
```

Can the same be done using TERGM?

I have fit the network using TERGM over 49 networks (1.net to 48.net)
`fit <- tergm(net_y.dyn~edges + nodematch("degree"), estimate = 'CMLE', times = c(0:48))`

I am getting the following warning

```
Starting maximum pseudolikelihood estimation (MPLE):
Evaluating the predictor and response matrix.
Maximizing the pseudolikelihood.
Finished MPLE.
Stopping at the initial estimate.
Evaluating log-likelihood at the estimate. 
Warning message:
In NetSeries(nw, times, NA.impute = control$CMLE.NA.impute) :
  Active vertex set varies from time point to time point. Estimation may not work.
```

Can anyone explain why this warning is showing?

Answer (score 0):

TERGM assumes the nodeset is fixed. The warning is because you are submitting a series of networks of different sizes.

Having said that, it is possible to incorporate exogenous node entry and exit processes into a TERGM -- such specifications are used in EpiModel framework, an example can be found here https://github.com/EpiModel/EpiModel-Gallery/tree/main/2018-08-SIwithVitalDynamics. A more general model with endogeneous node entry and exit is a subject of ongoing research.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for answering, I'd look into the github repo you suggested. Thanks a lot again!

Comment: @Su1, would you consider accepting the answer?